# used biocep with AWS?

Tags: r

Has anyone used `biocep` with AWS?  I see a lot of presentations online but nothing that seems to do a thorough job of walking you through the process.  There seems to be a lot of complexity to get your head around.  I was hoping someone could point me to particularly useful forum threads or [even better] some real tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Having just heard the author speak at useR2010, I believe that project is dead or has at least morphed into something else.